# Turnoff Spring Actuator /Health Logger in kubernates

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, spring-boot-actuator

I tunred off my spring boot actuator liveness/readiness logs in application.properties file with the

```
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled =true
management.health.livenessstate.enabled=true
management.health.readinessstate.enabled=true
```

But its logging the health check logs in Kubernate environment...

Is there any way to turnoff the healthcheck logs ...

Appreciate your response...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sure, if it works in Kubernets pod, but I know it just disable the console log for health check (the route keeps working)

```
logging:
 level:
   com:
    my:
      project:
        package:
          configuration:
            RequestLoggingFilterConfiguration: OFF
```

And that is my RequestLoggingFilterConfiguration class can be something like this:

```
@Configuration
class RequestLoggingFilterConfiguration : OncePerRequestFilter() {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    companion object {
        private val VISIBLE_TYPES: List<MediaType> = listOf(
            MediaType.valueOf("text/*"),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
            MediaType.valueOf("application/*+json"),
            MediaType.valueOf("application/*+xml"),
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA
        )
    }

    /**
     All your override methods here
   **/
}
```

Just for you know this code is Kotlin, but uses Spring Boot